# Private network with limit supply

Tags: private-blockchain, network

I'm just wondering if is possible to create a private network (Not development) with this characteristics:

- Max supply
- One account has all the supply already
- Nodes/peers can't mine
- Gas cost is always 0

Comment: It should be possible, but if nobody can mine then no block will be created, and that blockchain is kind of useless. There's quorum https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum, which uses go-ethereum to add some of the characteristics you are asking.

Comment: The idea is to use it as a distributed database

Comment: If nodes can't mine, then no transactions could be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with PoA (clique).

In such network, "mining" can only be done by specific nodes and initial balance is pre-determined.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is

1. Generate ethers in genesis block using `alloc` config param
2. Set block rewards to 0 in PoW chain.
3. Build geth to get your customized private-net with fixed supply and 0 block reward.

To set 0 block reward, in **go-ethereum/consensus/ethash/consensus.go** file change reward to 0.

```
FrontierBlockReward       = big.NewInt(0) // Block reward in wei for successfully mining a block
ByzantiumBlockReward      = big.NewInt(0) // Block reward in wei for successfully mining a block upward from Byzantium
ConstantinopleBlockReward = big.NewInt(0) // Block reward in wei for successfully mining a block upward from Constantinople
```